# Converting datetimes in Pandas with out-of-bounds epoch

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table containing datetime data which is defined as the number of seconds relative to the Windows epoch `1601-01-01`. (This is the native definition of datetimes in other software that I am using, which produced this data as output data.)

I attempted to convert these values into datetimes using `to_datetime` with `origin` set to `1601-01-01`, but discovered that my epoch is [out-of-bounds of Pandas's timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations), which are limited to the range `['1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225', '2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807']`. All of my datetimes themselves are within this range, it is only the epoch that is out-of-bounds.

The [Pandas documentation mentions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob) that you can store out-of-bounds datetimes in a `Period`. However, I don't understand how to use this to convert my epoch-defined values into datetimes.

How can I convert my values defined against an out-of-bounds epoch into datetimes? I understand that I could do this manually by adding 100 years in seconds to my number before conversion, but I was hoping there was some built-in method to perform an out-of-bounds conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
datetimes = df.sub(11644473600)['col'].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)
```

Output:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([13143340800, 13143350800, 13143460800], columns=['col'])
>>> df
           col
0  13143340800
1  13143350800
2  13143460800

>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df['col'] = df.sub(11644473600)['col'].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)
>>> df
                  col
0 2017-06-30 18:00:00
1 2017-06-30 20:46:40
2 2017-07-02 03:20:00
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're subtracting the difference between my epoch and the UNIX epoch in seconds, then converting that as a UNIX timestamp. It's not the native functionality I was hoping for, but if it works it will do.

Comment: FYI, the epoch difference in your answer seems to be 10 hours off. I had to switch to 11644509600 to get the correct datetimes.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Because your timestamp is actually just like Windows filetime timestamps, which they probably are. The universal way to convert that into a manageable datetime is to convert them into UNIX timestamps (which almost everything uses, including Python and Pandas).

Comment: If that worked, I'll update my answer to use the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I ended up settling on was to use a different epoch, then just adjust the year of produced date afterwards using `pd.DateOffset`.

```
import pandas as pd
def convert_win_datetime_to_pd_datetime(datetime):
    # The true epoch for Windows datetimes is 1601-01-01, but that is out-of-bounds for Pandas
    return pd.to_datetime(datetime, unit="s", origin="1701-01-01") - pd.DateOffset(years=100)
```

This function can accept a value or series and return the same structure.

I don't anticipate this approach causing any issues, and I found it more readable than using the difference between `1601-01-01` and `1970-01-01` as a magic number.

Answer (score 1):

Try `apply`ing `pd.Period` to your column:

```py
df['col'].apply(pd.Period)
```

With a sample dataframe:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['1234-01-01', '1492-01-01', '1601-01-01'], columns=['col'])
>>> df
          col
0  1234-01-01
1  1492-01-01
2  1601-01-01

>>> df.dtypes
col    object
dtype: object

>>> df['col'] = df['col'].apply(pd.Period)
>>> df
          col
0  1234-01-01
1  1492-01-01
2  1601-01-01

>>> df.dtypes
col    period[D]
dtype: object
```

Comment: My dates are all within Pandas' valid range, the problem is that they are defined as 13143340800 etc. and I want to convert that to 2017-01-01 etc. You seem to be assuming the opposite.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realize that! I'll try to come up with somvething else.

Comment: For 13143340800, does `2017-07-01` seem appropriate?

Comment: I'm going to leave this answer because I think it has value, but I've posted another answer which should do what you want.

Comment: You're correct, 13143340800 should be `2017-07-01`. Sorry about that typo.

Comment: Gotcha. @JRose see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70263560/17242583) below. I believe it does what you want.